# WebRTC stream and device

Tags: webrtc

For a WebRTC stream, how can I get the devices that streams it?
For each stream there's getAudio/VideoTracks() and for each track there's getCapabilities().deviceId, but getCapabilities() doesn't seem to be implemented.

I tested in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `getCapabilities` has not been implemented yet.

In the meantime use `track.label` and `track.kind` and compare it against the device label and kind you get from `enumerateDevices`. Works in Chrome and Firefox 46 (Firefox Developer Edition).

Comment: Regarding your edit, track.label was [added in Firefox 46](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866513).